# Should a foreign phrase that modifies an English noun go before or after that noun in English?

Tags: word-order, latin, noun-phrases, foreign-phrases, postpositive

I’m thinking of the placement of [the Latin phrase, *ad hominem*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ad_hominem) as it is used in English, not as it is used in Latin. Should it precede or follow its noun?

In other words, are both of these two sentences ok or only one? If so, then why is the one acceptable but the other not so?

1. The witness’s use of *ad hominem* attacks detracted from the value of his testimony.
2. The witness’s use of attacks *ad hominem* detracted from the value of his testimony.

Comment: I suspect that using them *before* treats it as a typical adjective, while *after* rolls it into a compound noun, as it is with standard English - e.g. *general auditor* vs *auditor general*.

Comment: [These Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attacks+ad+hominem%2Cad+hominem+attacks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattacks%20ad%20hominem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cad%20hominem%20attacks%3B%2Cc0) seem to suggest pre-positioning is normal in this case.

Comment: "Laissez-faire economy" or "economy laissez-faire"? The first sounds more natural. I'd go for "the witness's use of ad hominem attacks". What kind of attack did they engage in? Ad hominem.

Answer (score 2):

> I’m thinking of the placement of the Latin phrase, ad hominem as it is used in English, **not as it is used in Latin**. Should it precede or follow its noun?

## Before the noun; after the verb.

The bolded part is your clue. Postpositioning treats it like the prepositional phrase that it is in Latin.

In English, *[ad hominem](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2346)* is treated that way as an adverb ("argue *ad hominem*"; "designed *ad hominem*") where it's distinguished from *ad rem* and hews closer to its Latin meaning of "to/against the person".

It still means "concerning the persons of one's opponents rather than the substance of their arguments" as an adjective but it's been nativized and grammatically functions like a more exact form of "personal": "*ad hominem* attack"; "*ad hominem* appeal"; &c. Every one of the *OED*'s usage examples follows those patterns for the adv. and adj. senses.

You *can* treat the Latin phrase as a Latin phrase and place it in English as though it meant "to the person". You're just expecting your audience to parse it that way and most won't. They just know it describes a certain kind of effective but illegitimate argument and/or rhetorical fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

Given, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem *ad hominem attacks* would seem more logical.